# how can i reproduce a mysql blocked host error?

Tags: mysql

e.g.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blocked-host.html

```
Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors.
Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

basically, I wanna block localhost from being able to connect mysql somehow with this error

story:  in production, I had and endless stream of this in the logs, and basically the site was down until I SSH'ed in and did what it said:  run flush-hosts

so, my goal is to reproduce this so I can figure out a way to alert on it or stop it from happening!

But... I don't know how to make it happen!  Anyone know how?

So far I've tried random stuff like `telnet localhost 3306` and Ctrl-C'ing out if and stuff

Comment: What language are you using, can you show some code?

Comment: this is a Django/Python app! but really I think I wanna just block localhost from connecting to mysql  (if thats even possible!)

Comment: Have a look at this discussion: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/what-is-the-reason-of-host-host-name-is-blocked-in-mysql